# Many2many domain based on not-yet-created parent and parent's One2many entries

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I'm making a module for Odoo v9 that adds custom behaviour to sale.order and sale.order.line models.

I made a simple model (let's call it *passenger*) which is in a One2many relation with *sale.order*, like this:

```
class SaleOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'
    passengers_ids = fields.One2many('passenger', 'order_id')

class passenger(models.Model):
    _name = 'passenger'
    order_id = fields.Many2one('sale.order')
```

The way you add passengers to the sale order is through a regular One2many list.

On the other hand, I made a field inside *sale.order.line* that stores a Many2many relationship with *passenger*. Like this:

```
class SaleOrderLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'
    passengers_ids = fields.Many2many('passenger')
```

You add passengers to this field via a Many2many tags widget (though I don't think this makes any difference).

My problem arises when the sale order is still not created (but the form is being worked on), which means the sale order, sale order lines and passengers are all still "NewID" objects:
- I create the sale order passengers in the One2many list, and then need to be able to add them to the order lines' Many2many field, only filtering by those passengers that belong to the current sale order (picture something like `domain=[('order_id', '=', parent.id)]`).

The problem is, this filter does not apply until I hit "Save" on the sale order, and then Edit again to add the passengers to the order lines. Up to that point, **all** already existing passengers on the database are available to be added.

I've tried many domain filters, but none seem to work, and I vaguely remember reading something similar to this on a bug report that said this is indeed a problem and it is fixed in v11, but I cant quite recall if it was **really** the same problem.

Any insight into this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Only m2m field saves the records to database when you are working on the current form view. Try to use it smartly I can think of several tricks but require a lot of explanation and testing that cannot be done in a stackoverflow answer. just try to find a way to achieve this using `Many2many` relation ship